# Question about closed sets of K-topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology

I think that $\mathbb{R}$ in the $K$-topology is not normal, and I'm trying to prove this by finding two disjoint closed sets that are not separated by neighborhoods.

The candidates I am considering are the sets $[0,1]-K$ and $K$. Is this the correct choice? Are both these sets closed? Can they be separated by neighborhoods?

Please explain why or why they aren't closed because my book says $K$ is closed but I don't really know how to show it.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you please provide a definition of $K$-topology. I think many people have never heard of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$K$ is closed because it is the complement of the union $(-\infty,-1)\cup((-2,3)\setminus K)\cup(2,\infty)$ which is open in the $K$ topology (if this isn't clear from your definition of the $K$ topology, then you may have a different one from what [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-topology) uses).

I would suggest using the two closed subsets $\{0\}$ and $K$. The first is closed because the $K$-topology is strictly finer than the usual topology and so all singletons are closed. I'll leave the proof that these two subsets can't be separated by disjoint open neighbourhoods to you.

Comment: No problem. This is actually the first time I've heard of this strange topology but it certainly is interesting.